# Ordenar uma struct

Tags: c, classificação, struct, array

Tem alguma forma de ordenar uma `struct` da forma:

```
struct cidadecoord
{
  char cidade[90];
  int coordx, coordy;
}cidades[N];
```

N vale 30 no caso, e eu gostaria de ordenar as coordenas x e y, para descobrir quais eram as cidades mais ao leste, oeste, norte e sul. Estou com dificuldades, pois não sei como ordenar mantendo a informação do nome da cidade de cada coordenada.

Comment: Tudo depende da ordem da sua ordenação. Como você quer ordenar? Em qual prioridade? Primeiro x, depois y? Uma distância, ou seja, sqrt(x^2 + y^2), e depois o nome? Ou o nome vem primeiro?

Comment: @rodrigogq No caso, eu precisaria ordenar x e y, separadamente. Os valores de x ordenados me daria a cidade mais ao oeste (o menor valor de x) mais ao leste (o maior valor de x) e com os valores de y ordenados eu saberia a cidade mais ao norte  e a mais ao sul, da mesma forma.

Comment: Precisa ordenar mesmo ou só achar essas informações? Se for nem precisa ordenar !

Comment: @rodrigogq Pensei em ordenar, porque achei que seria mais fácil para achar o maior e menor valor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a ideia é só pegar as cidades mais ao norte, sul, leste e oeste, pode fazer assim:

```
int indNorte = 0;
int indSul = 0;
int indLeste = 0;
int indOeste = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if(cidades[indNorte].coordy < cidades[i].coordy) indNorte = i;
    if(cidades[indSul  ].coordy > cidades[i].coordy) indSul = i;
    if(cidades[indLeste].coordx < cidades[i].coordx) indLeste = i;
    if(cidades[indOeste].coordx > cidades[i].coordx) indOeste = i;
}
```

Comment: Você precisa passar por todos os pontos necessariamente. Ordenar por várias camadas vai ser pior. Aqui você já obtém o índice das cidades sem precisar ordenar tudo.

Comment: Eu precisaria criar outras structs para indNorte, indSul, indLeste e indOeste ou dessa forma que você fez já é suficiente?

Comment: Depende.. se você for usar para exibir as cidades, pode usar direto este índice para pegar pelo nome.. Exemplo, nome da cidade mais ao norte será `cidades[indNorte].cidade`. Se você for retornar de uma função, pode fazer uma struct ou algo semelhante (como um array de índices, cada um representando mais ao norte, sul, leste e oeste). Vai de gosto.

Comment: Entendi! Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Usa a função `qsort()` da biblioteca standard com a tua própria função de ordenação

```
int orderbyx(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct cidadecoord *aa = a;
    const struct cidadecoord *bb = b;
    return aa->coordx - bb->coordx;
}
int orderbyy(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct cidadecoord *aa = a;
    const struct cidadecoord *bb = b;
    return aa->coordy - bb->coordy;
}

/* ... */
qsort(cidades, N, sizeof *cidades, orderbyx);
/* cidades[0] tem a cidade com x menor */
/* cidades[N-1] tem a cidade com x maior */

/* ... */
qsort(cidades, N, sizeof *cidades, orderbyy);
/* cidades[0] tem a cidade com y menor */
/* cidades[N-1] tem a cidade com y maior */
```